# How do we do classes in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have a problem with writing classes in Julia. I have looked at the documentation and I haven't seen any docs on classes.

In Python, classes are, for example,

```py
class Dog:
   # ----blah blah---
```

How is this possible in Julia?

Comment: Short answer: we don't.

Comment: A class is like a `struct` + methods. In Julia those are (deliberately) not bundled together. So just create a `struct` and add methods. https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/

Comment: So it is structs + methods instead of classes in Julia.
Wow thank you.

Comment: @tholy please give me a simple example to demonstrate so at least for a better understanding.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Julia does not have classes. Instead we define new types and then define methods on those types. Methods are not "owned" by the types they operate on. Instead, a method can be said to belong to a [generic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_function) of the same name as the method. For instance, there are many versions ("methods") of the `length` function; together they form the generic function `length`.

Here's an extended example of the Julian approach to programming with types and methods. New types are declared using the `struct` keyword:

```
struct Person
    name::String
    age::Int64
end
```

Now we can define methods on the `Person` type:

```
name(p::Person) = p.name
age(p::Person) = p.age

bio(p::Person) = println("My name is ", name(p)," and I am ", age(p), " years old.")
```

Methods can be defined for different combinations of argument types. To illustrate this, let's first define some new types:

```
abstract type Pet end

struct Cat <: Pet
    name::String
    color::String
end

name(c::Cat) = c.name
color(c::Cat) = c.color
species(::Cat) = "cat"

struct Dog <: Pet
    name::String
    color::String
end

name(d::Dog) = d.name
color(d::Dog) = d.color
species(::Dog) = "dog"

bio(p::Pet) = println("I have a ", color(p), " ", species(p), " named ", name(p), ".")

struct Plant
    type::String
end

type(p::Plant) = p.type
bio(p::Plant) = println("I have a ", type(p), " house plant.")
```

At this point we can see that we've defined three different one-argument methods for `bio`:

```
julia> methods(bio)
  3 methods for generic function "bio":
[1] bio(p::Plant) in Main at REPL[17]:1
[2] bio(p::Person) in Main at REPL[4]:1
[3] bio(p::Pet) in Main at REPL[14]:1
```

Note the comment in the output of `methods(bio)`: "3 methods for generic function 'bio'". We see that `bio` is a *generic function* that currently has 3 methods defined for different function [signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature). Now let's add a two-argument method for `bio`:

```
function bio(person::Person, possession)
    bio(person)
    bio(possession)
end
```

Notice that this function is generic in the `possession` argument, since the internal call to `bio(possession)` will work whether the `possession` is a plant, cat, or dog! So we now have four total methods for `bio`:

```
julia> methods(bio)
  4 methods for generic function "bio":
[1] bio(p::Plant) in Main at REPL[17]:1
[2] bio(p::Person) in Main at REPL[4]:1
[3] bio(p::Pet) in Main at REPL[14]:1
[4] bio(person::Person, possession) in Main at REPL[18]:1
```

Now let's create a few instances of our types:

```
alice = Person("Alice", 37)
cat = Cat("Socks", "black")
dog = Dog("Roger", "brown")
plant = Plant("Boston Fern")
```

So finally we can test our `bio` methods:

```
julia> bio(alice, cat)
My name is Alice and I am 37 years old.
I have a black cat named Socks.

julia> bio(alice, dog)
My name is Alice and I am 37 years old.
I have a brown dog named Roger.

julia> bio(alice, plant)
My name is Alice and I am 37 years old.
I have a Boston Fern house plant.
```

Side note: Modules are used primarily for [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) management. A single module can contain the definitions for multiple types and multiple methods.

Comment: I find this elaborates more on my question.

Comment: Another thing is that  I think it would be better to use "planttype" instead of using "type" when defining the struct for Plant. This makes sense because "type" is reserved though it is depreciated but when you are writing the code with "type", Julia thinks that you want to construct a "type".
And then finally, how important is the following lines of codes?
name(d::Dog) = d.name
color(d::Dog) = d.color
species(::Dog) = "dog"

Comment: @kkirui Good point about "type". Although, I'm running Julia v1.1 and I don't see any warnings about using "type". I think it should be ok in Julia v1.0 or higher.

Comment: In this example, the `name`, `color`, and `species` methods seem a little superfluous. However, they help define an "interface" on the abstract type `Pet`. Note that the `bio(p::Pet)` method works on any sub-type of `Pet` because the `name`, `color`, and `species` methods have been implemented for each sub-type. This allows the internal representation of `Cat`s and `Dog`s to change at any point in the future, if necessary, as long the `name`, `color`, and `species` methods are still implemented and still return the same type of output.

Comment: Inside the class in Python, there is this function 
``` python
def __init__():
 blah
end
```
Is it possibe to add in the above answer?
@Cameron Beiganek

Comment: I don't quite understand why all the methods (`name`, `color`, `species`, etc) are declared outside the struct. I thought the purpose of a class was to hold a set of attributes and methods which belong to it and not in the global namespace. (E.g. so I can invoke them using dot-notation: `alice.bio()`). Can I do that in Julia?

Comment: @Bill Julia does not have classes. Functions in Julia use multiple dispatch, which means that the correct method to dispatch is chosen by looking at the types of all the positional arguments, not just the first argument. The type of the object provided as the first argument to a function doesn't "own" the method any more than the types of the other arguments, so it doesn't make sense to bundle methods with structs. In fact, the reverse occurs---all the different methods for `foo` can be thought of as members of the _generic_ function `foo`.

Comment: @Bill This approach of keeping data types separate from functions/methods is common in functional languages, including R.

Comment: Thanks @Cameron Beiganek. I'm reading about multiple dispatch. I think I get it but how do I avoid the practical issue of name conflicts? For example, I created a method for my object: `step(gym::CartPole, u)` and put them both in a module and now I get `WARNING: both CartPoleBTEnv and Base export "step"; uses of it in module Main must be qualified`. Are there any simple examples or tutorials on how to do this?

Comment: For beginners like myself, I found a gentle introduction to functions and methods in Julia here: [Think Julia](https://benlauwens.github.io/ThinkJulia.jl/latest/book.html#chap17).

Comment: @Bill Your question about name conflicts is worthy of a separate Stack Overflow question. But in brief, you can either rename your function, call it via `CartPoleBTEnv.step()`, or make it an extension of the `Base.step` function. The last option is convenient, but it's not ideal since the Base `step` function has the meaning "get the step size of an `AbstractRange` object", which is completely different from the meaning of your `step` function. I think it's unfortunate that they chose the name `step` for that function in Base. In my opinion, `stepsize` would have been better.

Comment: It's not just `step`. Function names like `begin`, `end`, `break`, `catch`, `show`, `export` would all create similar conflicts. I did extend `Base.step` in the end, but then you live in fear that some other process may call your method one day!

Answer (score 10):

The closest one can get to classes with methods in Julia is the module:

```
module DogClass

export Dog, bark

struct Dog
    name::String
end

function bark(d::Dog)
    println(d.name, " says woof!")
end

end #MODULE

using .DogClass  # note the . here, means look locally for module, not library

mydog = Dog("Fido")

bark(mydog)
```

Comment: The module seems superfluous - indeed this seems like an inappropriate use of modules. But your Dog struct and bark function are great examples of how to get this functionality.

Comment: This is a toy example. While porting a substantial class from something such as C++, a user might want to emulate private methods, which using a module sort-of allows (though not entirely) since only public methods would be exported.

Comment: Thanks so much. I understand now more on using modules